# How make SEO friendly url without .php

Tags: nginx

I want to use SEO friendly url`s like  site.com/page
So i looking for a (nginx) rewrite to change /page.php to /page.

My server is running Nginx + PHP-FPM 5.6
I also use images,js,css in the map /static/

What i tried:

```
    try_files $uri $uri/ /;
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Redesign your application to use a front controller.

Comment: Have you tried this workaround to solve your issue? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911297/how-to-remove-both-php-and-html-extensions-from-url-using-nginx

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
try_files $uri $uri.php =404;
```

It's pretty pointless, though, for SEO; I've never seen any credible evidence that having ".php" at the end of the path portion of a URL negatively impacts search results.